Azure function, wait for config change to complete
I am running an Azure function (Python) app with a custom Docker image. I deploy this image using a pipeline, consisting of the following steps

Build and tag new image
Push new image
Change azure function app configuration using the azure cli, az functionapp config container set --docker-image-custom-name <image> (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/config/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-config-container-set)
Run integration tests on the function app

When I change the configuration it takes some time for the changes to take effect, i.e. before the new image is actually running. I've noticed that therefore the integration tests sometimes run on the old image.
I was wondering if there is a way to 'wait' for the change to have taken effect.
I tried by using az functionapp config container show, but the configuration change immediately takes effect.
I could of course just wait for a few seconds, but that is not ideal for obvious reasons.
How do other people deal with this?

I could of course just wait for a few seconds, but that is not ideal for obvious reasons. - well, why not? If you can't find another workaround that is easy/quick to implement, you should consider that option. Just add a task that uses sleep (bash) or Start-Sleep (Powershell) before running the integration tests.

Agreed, i might have exagerrated a bit ;). My main reason is that we share an agent pool with other teams and would like to keep pipelines as short as possible, waiting for 20 - 30 secs to be sure it's deployed would be something i'd like to avoid if possible. Hence the question here, to see if there are other ideas.

"My main reason is that we share an agent pool with other teams and would like to keep pipelines as short as possible" - The current issue is that container updates do not take effect immediately, and waiting for them to take effect is unavoidable.

If you just want to reduce pipeline waiting time so that other teams can get the agent as soon as possible, you can consider putting container update and run test into two separate pipelines. Let the container update pipeline trigger the run test pipeline. If the time between the two pipelines is not enough for the container update to complete, you still need to add some wait time in the run test pipeline.

I've created a powershell script to help with this scenario when using deployment slots.
The key to the script is that it queries the current state of the function on a timer and waits for the desired state.
It does the following:

Starts the staging slot (it is necessary to have both slots running to swap).
Waits for the slot to be in a running state.
Swaps the slots.
Stops the staging slot.
Waits for the staging slot to be in a stopped state.

I believe something similar could be used for your purposes.
#Assuming your slots are named production and staging
param ($resourceGroupName, $functionAppName)

Write-Output "${resourceGroupName}" 
Write-Output "${functionAppName}"

#Function Wait Function App State
#Used to wait for the function to either be running or stopped
function Wait-FunctionAppState {
    param (
        [string]$ResourceGroupName,
        [string]$FunctionAppName,
        [string]$SlotName = "production",
        [string]$DesiredState,
        [int]$TimeoutInSeconds = 60,
        [int]$PollingIntervalInSeconds = 10
    )

    $elapsedTime = 0

    while ($elapsedTime -lt $TimeoutInSeconds) {
        $currentState = az functionapp show `
            --resource-group $ResourceGroupName `
            --name $FunctionAppName `
            --slot $SlotName `
            --query "state" -o tsv

        Write-Output "Current state of slot '$SlotName': $currentState"

        if ($currentState -eq $DesiredState) {
            Write-Output "Slot '$SlotName' has reached the desired state '$DesiredState'."
            return $true
        }

        Start-Sleep -Seconds $PollingIntervalInSeconds
        $elapsedTime += $PollingIntervalInSeconds
    }

    Write-Error "Timeout: Slot '$SlotName' did not reach the state '$DesiredState' within $TimeoutInSeconds seconds."
    return $false
}

# Start the staging slot
az functionapp start --resource-group "${resourceGroupName}" --name "${functionAppName}" --slot "staging"

# Wait until the staging slot is running
Wait-FunctionAppState -ResourceGroupName "${resourceGroupName}" `
                      -FunctionAppName "${functionAppName}" `
                      -SlotName "staging" `
                      -DesiredState "Running"

# Swap the slots
az functionapp deployment slot swap --resource-group "${resourceGroupName}" --name "${functionAppName}" --slot "staging" --target-slot "production"

# Stop the staging slot
az functionapp stop --resource-group "${resourceGroupName}" --name "${functionAppName}" --slot "staging"

# Wait until the staging slot is stopped
Wait-FunctionAppState -ResourceGroupName "${resourceGroupName}" `
                      -FunctionAppName "${functionAppName}" `
                      -SlotName "staging" `
                      -DesiredState "Stopped"

Write-Output "Function App Slots Swapped" 
Exit 0

